# MyBatis Generator plugin table tag

Tags: reverse-engineering, mybatis

Blog table consists of a one-to-one association with Author table and my java classes should look like this as expected.

public class Blog {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String url;
private Author author;
```

//getters and setters
}

public class Author {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
```

}

I have written a "generatorConfig.xml" as shown below

---

```
</table>
<table schema="blog_ibatis" tableName="Post" >

</table>
<table schema="blog_ibatis" tableName="Tag" >

</table>
<table schema="blog_ibatis" tableName="Author" >

</table>
```

---

And used Mybatis Generator plug-in to generate the java classes using reverse engineering technique.
But the generated java classes has no association between them and they are as shown below 
public class Blog {
private int id;

```
enter code here

private String name;
private String url;
// Reference to Author is not present in this class
```

}

public class Author {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the MyBatis generator does not support associations. You have to place them manually. See [*IBatis (MyBatis): Handling Joins: Advanced Result Mapping, Association, Collections, N+1 Select Problem*](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ibatis-mybatis-handling-joins)